# Flutter build apk and installed got flash blank screen

Tags: android, flutter

when I build the flutter app and install on the real android phone I got these errors.

```
Launching lib/src/config/flavors/main_stage.dart on DUB AL00 in debug mode...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
E/flutter (32542): [ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl.cc(70)] Failed to setup Skia Gr context.
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:52745/fiENvL9drJE=/ws
Exited (sigterm)
```

I googled there are saying add --enable-software-rendering , this works with debug mode
but how can I make work when I build an installable APK? If I run as relase mode this argument does not work.

anyone can help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`flutter run --enable-software-rendering` should work as a work-around. CC @mit-mit, @cbracken @chinmaygarde I thought that we had decided to make Android Emulators default to software rendering? (I can't seem to find the issue tracking that)?
[source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11094#issuecomment-370289585)

Comment: You should answer here not request.

Answer (score 0):

Run > Edit Config > Additional Argument > "--enable-software-rendering"

Comment: on android studio